# Info path form fields as columns - sharepoint 2013

Tags: infopath, form, forms-library

I have a forms library - Infopath forms- in SharePoint 2013. How can I show the form fields as library columns?

Answer (score 1):

After you have designed the form. Go to:

File > Publish > SharePoint Server.

1. Select your site and click next
2. Choose Form Library radio button and click next
3. Create a new form library click next
4. Choose a name and click next

In the next step of the publishing wizard you can select the fields you want to add to the list view as columns. Just choose the fields you like and follow through the wizard.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get a copy of the InfoPath form used in that library and edit it using InfoPath Designer (not InfoPath Filler). To get columns to appear in your library they need to be promoted though the publishing wizard from InfoPath Designer. (File > Publish > SharePoint Server)

More info: [Publish a form](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Publish-a-form-BD6EB030-B26B-4774-B22B-7C80E0089403)